# firebase isn't installing for swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, cocoapods

I've been trying to install firebase on swift but its not working!! 
you can check my podfile and error I get below

this is my podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'testt' do
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for testt
# Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
# Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

# Add the pods for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
# For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end
```

the error I get is :

```
[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=767%3A+unexpected+token+at+%27%27&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - Error during pod install: Encountered an unknown error (783: unexpected token at
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9672 [open] [81 comments]
   a day ago

 - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=767%3A+unexpected+token+at+%27%27&type=Issues
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9777 [closed] [3 comments]
   a day ago

 - Pod install results in JSON::ParserError - 767. Trying to install pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9694 [closed] [11 comments]
   5 days ago

and 10 more at:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=767%3A%20unexpected%20token%20at%20%27%27&type=Issues&utf8=✓
```

I've tried several older versions but still stuck and getting the same error

Comment: have you tried updating cocoapods & then reinstalling

Comment: yes I have but still facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

The above pods can be installed using the below versions,

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics','6.24.0'
pod 'Firebase/Auth','6.24.0'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore','6.24.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repo`

More details at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9672